# Wildcard expression to isolate files that end with pattern

Tags: r, wildcard

I'm trying to isolate all .tif files in R, but the following code also returns .tif.enp files. How to proceed?

```
 f <- list.files(getwd(), pattern=".*tif")
```

Comment: You need to escape special characters like dots, `pattern = "\\.tif$"`, and you can use `$` to be the end of the string.

Comment: Is `pattern` a regex pattern?

Comment: @Laurel. The help file says that the pattern argument is "an optional regular expression. Only file names which match the regular expression will be returned."

Comment: Thanks very much. I posted the solutions from @Gregor and rawr below for others to benefit from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both solutions from @Gregor and @rawr work well.

```
f <- list.files(getwd(), pattern="\\.tif$") 
f <- Sys.glob(file.path(getwd(), '*tif'))
```

Comment: The second answer is a little dangerous as it could match names of files such as `pontif.jpeg`.

Comment: @lmo no it doesn't

Comment: @rawr. Perhaps I'm confused about the Sys.glob() function or something, but `grep('*tif', c("tiff", "pontif.jpeg", "tif"))` returns `1 2 3`.

Comment: @lmo `grep(glob2rx('*tif'), c("tiff", "pontif.jpeg", "tif"))`

Comment: @rawr. those are some interesting functions. I'll have to take a look at them in more detail. Thanks.